# Monthly retention rate query tweaking

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am calculating month on month retention using the following code:

```
WITH monthly_user_counts AS (
  SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',event_date),MONTH) AS obs_date,
    user_pseudo_id
  FROM
    `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
),
returning_users AS (
  SELECT
    curr.obs_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT prev.user_pseudo_id) AS returning_user_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT curr.user_pseudo_id) AS total_users
  FROM
    monthly_user_counts curr
  LEFT JOIN
    monthly_user_counts prev
  ON
    curr.user_pseudo_id = prev.user_pseudo_id AND prev.obs_date =  DATE_SUB(curr.obs_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  GROUP BY
    curr.obs_date
),
inter AS (
  SELECT
    obs_date,
    returning_user_count,
    total_users,
    round((returning_user_count * 100.0 / total_users),1) AS monthly_retention
  FROM
    returning_users
  ORDER BY
    obs_date
)

SELECT * FROM inter;
```

This is giving retention rate as: returning users / total users of the current month. Whereas I want: returning users / total users of the previous month.

Comment: So you want to join on the month following rather than the one prior?

Comment: Isn’t your date logic in returning_users going to only return a user on the same date in the previous month, rather than at anytime in the month? Is that the correct logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if we perform the aggregation to month at the very beginning, and then eliminate the need to do a self-join by user_id by just simply using a window function that counts. That way you'll know if its a returning user if the count is more than just 1.

```
WITH monthly_users AS (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT DATE_TRUNC(
      PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date), 
      MONTH
    ) AS obs_date, 
    user_pseudo_id 
  FROM 
    `rayn-deen-app.analytics_317927526.events_*`
), 
ranked AS (
  SELECT 
    user_pseudo_id, 
    obs_date, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id 
      ORDER BY 
        obs_date ASC
    ) AS TIMES_SEEN 
  FROM 
    monthly_users
), 
summary AS (
  SELECT 
    obs_date, 
    count(1) AS total_users, 
    sum(
      case when TIMES_SEEN = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) as first_users, 
    sum(
      case when TIMES_SEEN = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ) as returning_users 
FROM ranked
  GROUP BY 
    obs_date
) 
SELECT 
  obs_date, 
  round(
    (
      returning_users * 100.0 / total_users
    ), 
    1
  ) AS monthly_retention 
FROM 
  summary
```